# AJAX Request returns 200 OK but jQuery error callback was not called

Tags: ajax, playframework

I try to connction to my service side (play framwork) with ajax
this is my client code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    data: {name: 'bbb'}
});
```

and client side

```
public static Result myfunction(String name)
{
    return ok(name);
}
```

I'm just trying to learn because of this it's a really simple example
Many thanks for any help!(:

Comment: I want that the name will return from client server, If it will be more clear :public static Result myfunction(String name)
{
    return ok("my name is"+name);
} and I want to get in client side :my name is bbb

Comment: You don't have a jQuery callback so of course it's not getting called.  You probably also don't want jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't having any callback function to handle your response data in your snippet as @Ryan mentioned. Try this,

`$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    data: {name: 'bbb'},
    success : processData       // Add this line with your existing snippet.
});`

Following function will be invoke, when your request is success.

`function processData(data) {
    alert(data); 
   //do some stuff
}`